# Document updates using mongo-ruby-driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-ruby, nosql

Assuming the following:

```
irb> x
irb> => {"_id"=> 123456, "welcome"=>"Hi!", "welcome2" => "Enjoy your stay!"}
irb> coll.class
irb> => Mongo::Collection
```

How can I use the raw mongo-ruby-driver to update the document corresponding to x by using both the rewriting method and the atomic update method? (See http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#Updating_a_Document)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

given your example output, if you want to use the rewriting method it would be like this:

```
coll.update({"_id" => x["_id"]}, x)
```

or if you want to atomically change a value, it would be like this:

```
coll.update({"_id" => x["_id"]}, {"$set" => {"welcome" => "Hello There"}})
```

Comment: Also, if you want to update multiple documents:

`coll.update({<search criteria>}, {"$set" => {<update>}}, {:multi => true })`

Just thought I'd add that since I couldn't find it anywhere.